# Should you append data to flatlist or replace data in flatlist ( best practices for heavy components in flatlist )?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I am using react-native-socials to display tweet data from a backend API, in a flatlist. I have implemented pullToRefresh and also refresh the feed, when we reach the end.

So each element in the feed is a tweet and is displayed in a twitter component from the library.

I am using `useState` to set the feed and that reloads the flatlist.

Currently I am replacing the feed with the new data.

### Problem

After a few times feed is updated from the backend by `pullToRefresh`, I am getting an `undefined` in this `Twitter` element from the library.

[image: TweetImage]

Here's the code for the `feed page` :

```js
~~~ SNIP Imports ~~~
function FeedScreen({ navigation, route, typeOfFeed }) {
    const typeOfFeed = 1;
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [tcursor, settCursor] = useState({
      previous: "",
      next: "",
    });
    const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);
    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
    const refContainer = useRef(null);
    const showToast = (message) => {
      ToastAndroid.show(message, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      loadFeed(typeOfFeed);
    }, []);
  
    const loadFeed = async (typeOfFeed, old = false) => {
      setRefreshing(true);
      let userData = await getAndRefreshToken();
      if (userData) {
        setUser(userData);
      }
      postsApi.setAuthToken(userData["idToken"]["jwtToken"]);
      let url = tcursor.next;

      const deDupeIt = (...arrs) => [...new Set([].concat(...arrs))];
      const response = await postsApi.getPosts(typeOfFeed, url);
      if (response.ok) {
        if (response.data[0].id == feed[0]?.id) {
          ToastAndroid.show("No new posts", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        } else if (response.data.length > 0) {
          // This code is for adding a fixed length of array elements
          //
          // let oldLength = feed.length;
          // const feedNew = deDupeIt(feed, response.data);
          // if (feedNew.length <= oldLength) {
          //   oldLength = 0;
          // }
          // const feed100 = feedNew.slice(Math.max(feedNew.length - oldLength, 0));
          //
        settCursor({
            next: response.headers.next,
            previous: response.headers.previous,
        });
          setFeed(response.data);
        }
      } else {
        ToastAndroid.show("No new posts", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        console.error(response.problem);
      }
      setRefreshing(false);
    };
    return (
        <Screen style={styles.screen}>
          {feed.length != 0 ? (
            <PostFlatlist
              refContainer={refContainer}
              feed={feed}
              onRefresh={() => {
                loadFeed(typeOfFeed);
              }}
              refreshing={refreshing}
              handleBookmark={handleBookmark}
              onEndReached={() => {
                if (refContainer.current) {
                  refContainer.current.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: 0 });
                }
                loadFeed(typeOfFeed, true);
              }}
              onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
            />
          ) : (
            <View
              style={{
                height: "100%",
                width: "100%",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
            >
              {refreshing ? (
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={colors.twitterBlue} />
              ) : (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    loadFeed(typeOfFeed);
                  }}
                  style={styles.appButtonContainer}
                >
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="reload" size={30} color="black" />
                  <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>Reload Feed</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
          )}
        </Screen>
      );
    }
```

#### Code for `PostFlatlist.js`

```js
~~~ SNIP Imports ~~~

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <View
    style={{
      padding: 10,
      borderRadius: 35,
      backgroundColor: colors.white,
    }}
  >
    {item.type == postType.TWEET && (
      <Twitter useCustomTweetExtendedData={item.content} />
    )}
  </View>
);

function PostFlatlist({
  feed,
  style,
  refreshing,
  onRefresh,
  handleBookmark,
  ListHeaderComponent,
  onEndReached,
  onEndReachedThreshold,
  refContainer,
}) {
  return (
    <FlatList
      ref={refContainer}
      data={feed}
      keyExtractor={(post) => {
        return post.id.toString();
      }}
      ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderComponent}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
      refreshing={refreshing}
      onRefresh={onRefresh}
      onEndReached={onEndReached}
      onEndReachedThreshold={onEndReachedThreshold}
    />
  );
}

export default PostFlatlist;
```

Comment: Can you clarify or expand upon what "After a few feed load, I am getting an undefined in this Twitter element from the library." actually means? What is undefined? What Twitter element? From what library? Is there an error?

Comment: @DrewReese sorry, for writing that out haphazardly. Updated with more context. Thanks for looking into it. I've mentioned the library and the twitter element is from that library itself.

Comment: From what I can tell you replace the feed on each refresh with `setFeed(response.data);` so this looks like a data issue from the backend. Are you saying that after a few refreshes that previously defined data is now undefined?

Comment: yes but only one of them. However I checked separately with Postman and the data seems to be there. Since it's paginated, so 10 elements at a time and there are pages after that as well. I could see all the ten elements there. Probably it's a `useState` async issue, not sure. I tried logging intermittently and also adding checks to avoid `undefined` values but in vain.